# Displaying multideminsional arrays using underscore.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a model containing attributes in a multidimensional array. In the template function of  the view, I want to unpack this array but I'm not sure how to accomplish this with underscore.js. I've looked around on google, but I can't seem to find a straightforward example.

For Example, here is a multidimensional array:

```
array(
    "elementTag" => "li",
    "elementClass" => "dashboard",
    "elementContent" => array(
        "elementTag" => "a",
        "elementContent" => "The Value I want to Display!!!",
        "href" => "#home"
    )
)
```

If my template: looks like this:

```
template: _.template('<<%= elementTag %> class="<%= elementClass %>">...</<%= elementContent %>>')
```

How would I display the value of `elementContent` ?:

> The Value I want to Display!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood you, `<%= elementContent.elementContent %>` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript uses dot notation to access properties of objects.

For example, you posted your array as it would appear in php, in JavaScript you would create that structure as follows:

```
var myObject = {
    "elementTag": "li",
    "elementClass": "dashboard",
    "elementContent": {
        "elementTag": "a",
        "elementContent": "The Value I want to Display!!!",
        "href": "#home"
    }
}
```

You can then pass that to a constructor on your backbone model, which is what the collection
does internally when you call fetch/reset etc.

```
var model = new ElementModel(myObject)

model.get('elementClass') // returns "dashboard"
model.get('elementContent') // returns the element content object
model.get('elementContent').elementTag // returns the "a"

var myObject = model.toJSON() // returns the object in the same format as above

myObject.elementClass // "dashBoard"
myObject.elementContent.elementTag // "a"
```

Commonly in backbone you pass the result of `model.toJSON()` to the underscore template, so as @fencliff rightly answered, all of the properties of your object are available in the template in the format

```
<%= elementTag %>
<%= elementClass %>
<%= elementContent.elementContent %>
// etc.
```